# Question about this Calculus problem

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have a small question about how to approach this problem:

$\dfrac{d}{dx}\left((-4x^2-9)^6 * (6x^2+17)^{15}\right)$

Am I correct in thinking that I should do the Product Rule and THEN the Chain rule?

Comment: I assume you are differentiating..Yes you are correct. Use the product rule and then use the chain rule to differentiate each expression.

Comment: Yes I am, sorry for not specifying in my post. And thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Let $f(x) =(-4x^2-9)^6$ and $g(x) = (6x^2+17)^{15}$. Then $h(x)=f(x)g(x)$
$$\implies h'(x)=f(x)g'(x)+g(x)f'(x)\tag{using product rule}$$
Then use the **chain rule** to find $f'(x)$ and $g'(x)$ and you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

$$f\left(x\right)=\left(-4x^2-9\right)^6*\left(6x^2+17\right)^{15}$$

$$ \;\quad \quad \quad =\left[-\left(4x^2+9\right)\right]^6*\left(6x^2+17\right)^{15}$$

$$ \;\;\;\quad \quad \quad =\left(-1\right)^6\left(4x^2+9\right)^6*\left(6x^2+17\right)^{15}$$

$$ \;\;\;\quad =\left(4x^2+9\right)^6*\left(6x^2+17\right)^{15}.$$

$f'\left(x\right)=D_x\left[\left(4x^2+9\right)^6\right]*\left(6x^2+17\right)^{15}+\left(4x^2+9\right)^6*D_x\left[\left(6x^2+17\right)^{15}\right]$

$f'\left(x\right)=6\left(4x^2+9\right)^5*D_x\left[4x^2+9\right]*\left(6x^2+17\right)^{15}+\left(4x^2+9\right)^6*15\left(6x^2+17\right)^{14}*D_x\left[6x^2+17\right]$

$f'\left(x\right)=6\left(4x^2+9\right)^5*8x*\left(6x^2+17\right)^{15}+\left(4x^2+9\right)^6*15\left(6x^2+17\right)^{14}*12x$

$f'\left(x\right)=48x\left(4x^2+9\right)^5\left(6x^2+17\right)^{15}+180x\left(4x^2+9\right)^6\left(6x^2+17\right)^{14}$